# GeoAlchemy get closest point to another point

Tags: python, postgis, geoalchemy

I have loaded into my db the `cities1000.txt` available [here](http://www.geonames.org/export/). I am attempting to create a query using `GeoAlchemy` to return the nearest city when I pass in Lat and Long. I currently have the query setup using `ST_ClosestPoint`, but it returns the same city no matter what lat/lon values I pass in. Here is the query I have written so far:

```py
q = db.session.query(cities1000,
                     func.ST_ClosestPoint(cities1000.c.geom,
                                          func.Geometry(func.ST_GeographyFromText(
                                              'POINT({} {})'.format(lon, lat))))).first()
```

Is `ST_ClosestPoint` what i'm looking for? Performance is a concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was unable to get this query working with `ST_ClosestPoint`, but the following seems to work with `ST_Distance`:

```
q = db.session.query(cities1000.c.name, 
                        cities1000.c.stateRegion, 
                        cities1000.c.country).\
    order_by(
    func.ST_Distance(cities1000.c.geom,
                     func.Geometry(func.ST_GeographyFromText(
                         'POINT({} {})'.format(lon, lat))))).limit(1).first()
```

Answer (score 5):

For performance reasons, it is better to use **`distance_centroid`** rather than **`ST_Distance`** in your query:

```
from geoalchemy2.comparator import Comparator
q = db.session.query(cities1000.c.name, 
                    cities1000.c.stateRegion, 
                    cities1000.c.country).\
    order_by(
    Comparator.distance_centroid(cities1000.c.geom,
                 func.Geometry(func.ST_GeographyFromText(
                     'POINT({} {})'.format(lon, lat))))).limit(1).first()
```

**`ST_Distance`** forces the database to calculate the distance between the query Point and every city in your table of candidate features, then sort them all and take the first result. Whereas the PostGIS **`<->`** operator that translates into **`distance_centroid`** in geoalchemy2 will do an index based Nearest Neighbour (NN) search. An index search partitions the space into multiple boxes (an R-Tree data structure) which considerably speeds up the nearest neighbor search for large databases.

To better understand how R-Tree and K-NN search work, you can read this great [post](https://blog.mapbox.com/a-dive-into-spatial-search-algorithms-ebd0c5e39d2a) on the Mapbox blog.